# Get process performance counter in C

Tags: c, windows, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I currently working on determining the CPU usage of a specific process in C. Currently we are using performance counters, but the counter we are using is the system counter, so i get the total CPU usage at the time we are measuring, but i need the CPU usage of the specific process we are running. Is there any way to get the counter for that specific process?  Update: Im using Windows 10

Comment: Getting those performance values are usually OS specific, do you have a specific OS in mind ?

Comment: Yes i'm using Windows 10, i missed that detail sorry

Answer (score 0):

With windows you would have the following API to get the system and process timings:

- [`GetSystemTimes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getsystemtimes) to get the total system timing.
- [`GetProcessTimes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes) to get timing for a specific process.
- [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess) to get current process handle.